# php getdate() vs date()

Tags: php, date, getdate

Theoretical question.

Imagine the situation. I need to get today date and time (not now, but today - the start of the day). I can do it with either this code:

```
$now = time();
$today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m", $now), date("d", $now), date("Y", $now)));
```

or this:

```
$now = getdate();
$today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, 0, $now['mon'], $now['mday'], $now['year']));
```

In most examples I've seen, the first way is used. The question is simple: why? The first one uses 3 function calls more to get month, day and year.

Comment: Probably habit? Or just luck - finding similarly coded examples. Performance wise there's likely no real difference between the two. For what it's worth, I prefer the second method. It reads better.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both of those options are pretty horrible -- if you're trying to get the current date at midnight as a formatted string, it's as simple as:

```
date('Y-m-d') . ' 00:00:00';
```

Or, if you want to be slightly more explicit,

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('today midnight'));
```

No need to do that wacky `mktime` thing.  Whoever wrote that code does not know what they are doing and/or is a copy-paste/cargo-cult developer.  If you really see that in "most examples," then the crowd you're hanging out with is *deeply troubled* and you should probably stop hanging out with them.

The only *interesting* thing that `mktime` does is attempt to work with the local timezone.  If your work is timezone sensitive, and you're working with PHP 5.3 or better, consider working with [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateTimeZone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) instead.  A demo from the PHP interactive prompt:

```
php > $utc = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
php > $pdt = new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
php > $midnight_utc = new DateTime('today midnight', $utc);
php > $midnight_utc->setTimeZone($pdt);
php > echo $midnight_utc->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
2011-04-08 17:00:00
```

(At the moment, it is the 9th in UTC, while it's the 8th in PDT.)